# Помогите доделать код python в нём есть ошибки по типу KeyError, SyntaxError

Tags: python, steam, syntax

Этот код должен выводить предметы с инвентаря steam и их стоимость

```
import time

import requests

wear_list = ['Factory New', 'Minimal Wear', 'Field-Tested', 'Well-Worn', 'Battle-Scarred']
INVENTORY_URL = 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{}/inventory/json/730/2'
MARKET_URL = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/'

def get_inventory(steamid):
    r = requests.get(INVENTORY_URL.format(steamid))
    return r.json()['rgDescriptions']

def extract_information(descriptions):
    for _, item in descriptions.items():
        tags = {i['category']: i for i in item['tags']}
        name = tags['market_name']
        yield {
            'name': name[name.find('|')+1:name.find('(')].strip(),
            'market_name': name,
            'market_hash_name': item['market_hash_name'],
            'wear': tags['Exterior']['name'],
            'gun': tags['Weapon']['name'],
            'stattrak': 'StatTrak' in tags['Quality']['name'],
            'marketable': item['marketable'],
        }

def get_prices(items):
    for item in items:
        if not item['marketable']:
            continue
        if item['wear'] not in wear_list:
            continue
            
        r = requests.get(
            MARKET_URL,
            params={
                'appid': '730',
                'currency': '2',
                'market_hash_name': item['market_hash_name']
            }
        )
        json_data = r.json()
        try:
            price = json_data['lowest_price']
        except KeyError:
            price = json_data['median_price']

        item['price'] = price[-4:]
        time.sleep(5)
        yield item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inventory = get_inventory('76561198996231585')
    item_information = extract_information(inventory)
    items = get_prices(item_information)
    for item in items:
        print('{name}: {price}'.format(**item))
```

---

**Ошибка**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "steam_price_item.py", line 59, in <module>
    for item in items:
  File "steam_price_item.py", line 31, in get_prices
    for item in items:
  File "steam_price_item.py", line 19, in extract_information
    market_name = tags['name'],
KeyError: 'name'
```

Comment: Запустите этот код в Python, и он вам сам выведет синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: File "steam_price_item.py", line 22
    'market_name' == name
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: да вот но я не знаю как её исправить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вашего словаря нет запятых после объявления ключа-значения.
Правка в функции `extract_information`:

```
yield {
        'name': name[name.find('|')+1:name.find('(')].strip(),
        'market_name': name,
        'market_hash_name': item['market_hash_name'],
        'wear': tags['Exterior']['name'],
        'gun': tags['Weapon']['name'],
        'stattrak': 'StatTrak' in tags['Quality']['name'],
        'marketable': item['marketable'],
}
```

Comment: Теперь вылезла следующая ошибка

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "steam_price_item.py", line 52, in <module>
    inventory = get_inventory('76561198996231585')
  File "steam_price_item.py", line 9, in get_inventory
    r = requests.get(STEAM_URL.format(steamid))
NameError: name 'STEAM_URL' is not defined```

Comment: В коде вы обращаетесь к переменной `STEAM_URL`, а ее нигде нет. Т.е. ожидается, что она будет заранее создана `STEAM_URL = "<ссылка>"`. Очень похоже, что там должно быть значение из `INVENTORY_URL`, тем более, что по смыслу подходит и `INVENTORY_URL` нигде неиспользуется

Comment: я заменил STEAM_URL на INVENTORY_URL и он выдал ошибку:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "steam_price_item.py", line 55, in <module>
    for item in items:
  File "steam_price_item.py", line 27, in get_prices
    for item in items:
  File "steam_price_item.py", line 15, in extract_information
    name = tags['market_name']
KeyError: 'market_name'

Comment: Это значит что в словаре `tags` нет ключа 'market_name'. Возможно, нужно проверять что ключ присутствует в словаре и не возвращать значение в `yield`

Comment: появилась другая ошибка посмотреть можно выше 2 ответ от меня

Comment: я так понял что у меня либо не хватает модуля и его надо установить или импортировать

Comment: @mezun, `"C:\Users\mezun0\Desktop\steam.python\urllib.py"` у вас файл в проекте называется как системная библиотека, переименуй его. А так, `urllib2` это либа для `urllib` для питона 2, а у вас питон 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "steam_price_item.py", line 59, in <module>
    for item in items:
  File "steam_price_item.py", line 31, in get_prices
    for item in items:
  File "steam_price_item.py", line 19, in extract_information
    name = tags['market_name']
KeyError: 'market_name'
**теперь есть другая ошибка**

Comment: @mezun, это такая же ошибка как была несколько комментариев выше. Кст, я уже ответил вам на ваш вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @mezun, смогли разобраться? :)

Comment: Нет, я буду рад если поможете, но и сам щас хочу розобраться попробовать

Comment: @mezun, ок, если что создайте новый вопрос с проблемой, если не получится разобраться